# Select single column as list from existing list using fieldname as string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Despite the numerous examples and threads on Linq and Lambda, I can't seem to find a way to select a single field from an existing list using the fieldname.
I think I'm relatively close with this code, but there's an error I don't understand :

```
           var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(returnEntityType), "item");
           var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, vi.BRONVELD);
           var projection = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

           var test = resultList.Select<returnEntityType, string>(projection).ToList();
```

Anyone any ideas how to get this done ?
Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What about DynamicLinq? `var test = resultList.Select("item").Cast<string>().ToList()`.

Comment: Marked takemyoxygen's answer as the solution since he was first and ponted me to the Dynamic Linq solution too.
IVAAAN123's solution works too without Dynamic Linq.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of `resultList` is `IQueryable<returnEntityType>` and you're using it to construct some kind of database query then you need to add type arguments to `Expression.Lambda` method:

```
var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<returnEntityType, string>>(propertyAccess)
```

Otherwise, if it's just a simple list or array, it's way simpler to use Dynamic Linq: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Your was close. Something like that should work:

```
    class Class
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    static Func<Class, string> GetLambda()
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Class), "item");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "A");
        var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<Class, string>>(property, parameter);

        return projection.Compile();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Class> list = new List<Class>();

        list.Add(new Class() { A = "class1-a", B = "class1-b" });
        list.Add(new Class() { A = "class2-a", B = "class2-b" });

        var select = list.Select(GetLambda()).ToList();
    }
```